# Problem In WPF datagrid editing with grouping enable

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, datagrid

Datagrid xaml code:

```
  <controls:DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <controls:DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                     </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </controls:DataGrid.GroupStyle>

        <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Student ID"  Width="90*" MinWidth="120" Binding="{Binding StudentId}"/>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Student Name" Width="90*" MinWidth="120" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Score" Width="100*" MinWidth="150" Binding="{Binding Score}"/>
        </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:DataGrid>
```

Here the code behind:

```
    void LoadDatagrid()
    {
        List<Student> _studentList = new List<Student>();

        _studentList.Add(new Student()
        {
            StudentId = 1,
            Name = "Paul Henriot",
            Department = "IT",
            Score = 540
        });

        _studentList.Add(new Student()
        {
            StudentId = 2,
            Name = "John Doe",
            Department = "IT",
            Score = 620
        });

        _studentList.Add(new Student()
        {
            StudentId = 3,
            Name = "Aria Cruz",
            Department = "ME",
            Score = 840
        });


        _studentList.Add(new Student()
        {
            StudentId = 4,
            Name = "Yoshi Latimer",
            Department = "ME",
            Score = 450
        });



        CollectionViewSource viewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
        viewSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Department"));
        viewSource.Source = _studentList; ;
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = viewSource.View;
    }

  public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }
    }
```

when i am trying to edit the score or name in first any one of the department,after editing that row jumps to down.

Need a help on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "row jumps to down" ? Do you mean the selection moves to the next row.I tried your code and find everything fine

Comment: The row itself moves to down(last row).

Comment: @biju have you tried in .Net 3.5?

Comment: No.I will try and let you know

Comment: @biju I am waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Solves my problem,I have added SortDescription to CollectionViewSource.

```
        CollectionViewSource viewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
        viewSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Department"));
        viewSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Department", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        viewSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("StudentId", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        viewSource.Source = _studentList; ;
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = viewSource.View;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is wrong, the binding path of the GroupStyle should be "Department", not "Name".

Change your code from:

```
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
```

to this:

```
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Department}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
```

It should work fine.

Comment: Have you replaced the path of the Binding? can you post the code after changing the binding path?

Comment: Issue i am facing is not related to group style.its strange  behaviour of datagrid after editing any row.

Comment: @Chand or somebody else? I think it's not fair to vote down my answer because you were giving the sample code using groupstyle, and I was trying to correct your previous code.